# RotateRight ith row of a matrix by i - 1

Tags: pattern-matching

first time stack exchange poster here! So I was working on a problem, the purpose of which was to write a function in the procedural style to rotate right the ith row of a matrix by i - 1 spaces. Ok, easy enough here was my implementation:

```
rotateRowsProcedural[mat_?MatrixQ] :=
(
  clonedMat = mat;
  i = 1;
  While[i <= Dimensions[clonedMat][[1]],
    clonedMat[[i]] = RotateRight[clonedMat[[i]], i - 1];
    i++;
  ];
  clonedMat
)
```

This was too boring so I decided I wanted to try and solve the problem using pattern matching approach and I came up with

```
rotateRowsPattern[matrix_?MatrixQ] := 
  matrix /. mat : {x__List} :> (RotateRight[#, Position[mat, #][[1, 1]] - 1] & /@ {x}) `
```

Now I thought this was pretty awesome I mean to me its the essence of *Mathematica*. However, I then decided to compare the efficiency of the two functions

```
Mean[Table[Timing[rotateRowsPattern[RandomInteger[{0, 10},{1000, 1000}]]][[1]], {100}]]
```

> 0.038844

```
Mean[Table[Timing[rotateRowsProcedural[RandomInteger[{0,10},{1000,1000}]]][[1]], {100}]]
```

> 0.0165361

I was surprised that the procedural implementation was faster. Then I thought it over and I think it is the case that calling `Position` in the pattern implementation must slow things down. My question then is if I want to use pattern matching how can I reference the location of `x` (from `x__List`) so that I don't have to call `Position`.

Also, I'm aware that combining `Map` and `Range` would be the most concise way to do this but I'm interested in the pattern matching.

Comment: "`Map` and `Range` would be the most concise way..." - nope. There's `MapIndexed[]`...

Comment: This isn't using pattern matching but for a speed up this may help: `rr[rin_] := (RotateRight[rin[[#]], # - 1] & /@ Range[Length[rin]])`.

Comment: I would also define your functions as `Module` as you are defining global variables (clonedmat) within them. It's best to keep track of the scope of such variables when you can.

Comment: @LarryS, please feel free to ignore my comment in that case. You are right that you did explicitly say that and I had missed that point in your post, my apologies.

Comment: @LarryS Be civil.  People are only attempting to be helpful.  Leaving stray global symbols in your function is bad programming practice and code exhibiting such will often be remarked upon.

Answer (score 8):

Since the summary of your question is:

> My question then is if I want to use pattern matching how can I reference the location of x (from x__List) so that I don't have to call Position.

I believe it is a duplicate of: [Position of a pattern-matched part of an expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19022/121)

Nevertheless in an effort to be helpful I would like to comment on your code.

Your procedural function should use `Module` to localize the Symbols that you use.  It would also be more efficient to calculate the dimensions only once:

```
rotateRowsProcedural[mat_?MatrixQ] := 
 Module[{clonedMat = mat, i = 1, dims = Dimensions[mat][[1]]},
  While[i <= dims, clonedMat[[i]] = RotateRight[clonedMat[[i]], i - 1]; i++;];
  clonedMat
 ]
```

Your pattern based function is a bit confusing.  The pattern matching is purely incidental to the operation of the function itself which could be written simply:

```
rotateRowsPattern[matrix_?MatrixQ] := 
 RotateRight[#, Position[matrix, #][[1, 1]] - 1] & /@ matrix
```

But both this function *and yours* will fail of there are repeated rows in the matrix.

You will see from the linked question above that there is no known easy and general solution to the problem of getting the position of a matched pattern.  However, for this simple application you can simply increment a counter for each row that is matched, which is perhaps in the spirit of what you intend:

```
rotateRows1[m_?MatrixQ] :=
  Module[{i = 0}, m /. x_?VectorQ :> RotateRight[x, i++]]
```

Still, this might be better formulated *without* the pattern matching as:

```
rotateRows2[m_?MatrixQ] := Module[{i = 0}, RotateRight[#, i++] & /@ m]
```

But this is really nothing more than a manual implementation of `MapIndexed`:

```
rotateRows3[m_?MatrixQ] := MapIndexed[RotateRight[#, #2[[1]] - 1] &, m]
```

Comment: One could of course do `Length[mat]` instead of `Dimensions[mat][[1]]`. Using `While[]` here looks a bit clunky; I'd have used `Do[]` myself.

Comment: @J.M. Agreed.  I was attempting to work with the OP's style, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (of Oz) thanks for the link. I'm somewhat disappointed that matched elements from the pattern matcher don't know by default their position but thus is life.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[1];
(m = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], {6, 5}]) // MatrixForm
i = 4;
```

Using `Pattern` matching:

```
res3 = m /. {k : Repeated[_, {i - 1}], h_, g___} :> {k, 
    RotateRight[h, i - 1], g}
```

More canonical solutions:

**Using `MapAt`:**

```
res1 = MapAt[RotateRight[#, i - 1] &, m, i]
```

**Using `SubsetMap`:**

```
res2 = SubsetMap[RotateRight[#, {0, i - 1}] &, m, {i}]
```

---

*Result*

```
MatrixForm /@ {m, res1, res2, res3}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 ReplacePart[#, {i} -> RotateRight[#[[i]], i - 1]] & @ mat

   // Thanks to @eldo
```

With `i=2`

```
mat = Partition[Range @ 25, 5];

With[{i=2},ReplacePart[#, {i} -> RotateRight[#[[i]], i - 1]] &]

(*{
   {1,2,3,4,5},
   {10,6,7,8,9},
   {11,12,13,14,15},
   {16,17,18,19,20},
   {21,22,23,24,25}
  } *)
```

Comment: It should be `ReplacePart[#, {i} -> RotateRight[#[[i]], i - 1]] & @ mat`

Comment: @eldo. Thanks! You are of course right (as usual!)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using `MapIndexed` just to "tag" each row with its row number and then use a replacement rule from there:

```
rot[mat_] := MapIndexed[List, mat] /. {x_, i_} :> RotateRight[x, i - 1]
```

Faster, but less readable, is to use `Transpose` and `Range` instead of `MapIndexed`:

```
rot[mat_] := Transpose[{mat, Range@Length@mat}] /. {x_, i_} :> RotateRight[x, i - 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = Partition[Range @ 25, 5];
i = 2;
```

**1.** If we can permanently change `m`:

```
m[[i]] = RotateRight[m[[i]], i - 1];

m // MatrixForm
```

[image]

**2.** Otherwise:

```
rot[x_, i_] :=
 Module[{m = x},
  m[[i]] = RotateRight[m[[i]], i - 1];
  m]

rot[m, 2] // MatrixForm
```

[image]