# Access list position from iterator?

Tags: list-manipulation, iterators

Consider a list, e.g.:

```
list = {a,b,c,d};
```

One can compose a `Table` by directly iterating through the list:

```
tab = Table[
        (*do something with i*)
      ,{i,list}]
```

This is useful, since we iterate through all elements in `list` without introducing an integer counter and notationally cleaner without having to deal with parts `list[[...]]`. However, sometimes we need to refer back to the position of `i` in `list`. Is there a convenient way to know the position of each `i` within `list` without calling `Position[list,i]`? What I mean is, does the iterator store and provide this information as well, so that there is some way to call it directly?

Comment: Somehow `Table[With[{i = list[[idx]]}, (* do something with i *)], {idx, Length@list}]` seems efficient enough, but there is `MapIndexed[]`. In any case, AFIAK, neither your form of `Table` nor `Map` makes the index available.

Comment: Closely related: [(84747)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84747/121).  Tangentially similar: [(19022)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19022/121)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) in the comments, a `Table` function iterator does not make the index available. However, one can use a different function [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) that instead of iterators provides two function arguments `#1` and `#2` referring to each element and its index respectively as it goes through the list:

```
tab = MapIndexed[
      (* do something with element `#1` while `#2` stores its position in `list` *)
      &,list]
```

This is notationally even shorter than the `Table`. And it generalizes straightforwardly to higher dimensional arrays.

Comment: Based on this self-answer with "exactly what is required" I have marked your question as "already has an answer."  Please let me know if you disagree.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would say, to find the other question one would already have to know to search for `Map`, whereas my question is broader as it asks about possible extra hidden information in generic iterators, such as in `Table`. The `MapIndexed` solution is more of a workaround solution for that.

Comment: (1) If your question remains marked as a duplicate it will remain visible (also to search engines) and serve as a redirect to the other question. (2) Nevertheless if you feel that `MapIndexed` is *a workaround* rather than *exactly what is required* I shall reopen this question, but you should change the wording of this self-answer to reflect that.  Shall I?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Oh, not really, I mean - I only wrote the comment because it seemed like you wanted to hear my personal opinion. Independent from that, I fully trust you on anything Mathematica! :) If you marked this as duplicate, I guess it is then, regardless of my personal impressions.

Comment: Yes, I was and am interested in your personal opinion.  As a Community Moderator I'm just a volunteer custodian, trying to do my best for all concerned, not The Hand of God, so I always care how people feel about closes etc.  I try to be consistent about my actions which is why I try to explain and/or argue my position, rather than just writing "I have decided" and leaving it at that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see. Thank you for spending your time on this! I have edited the answer now. Hopefully the new formulation makes this question and answer sufficiently distinct from previous ones.